# MongoDB on windows cannot bind to 28017

Tags: windows, mongodb

I am using MongoDB 2.6.1 on windows.  I have installed it as a service.  I am able to start the service and the process listens on 27017 successfully and I am able to connect to it, insert data and run queries.

The problem is that I cannot connec to the web interface at:

`http://localhost:28017`

When I recycle the service, I see that it cannot bind to the 28017 port because it looks like it is in use:

`[websvr] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:10048 Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. for socket: 0.0.0.0:28017`

However, when I run `netstat -anbo` it does not report any use of 28017.

**Update**: Adding more output from the log to show that REST is enabled, but the port is already in use.

```
2014-06-05T16:00:31.840-0700 [initandlisten] options: { config: "D:\MongoDb\bin\mongod.cfg", net: { http: { RESTInterfaceEnabled: true, enabled: true } }, service: true, storage: { dbPath: "e:\mongodb\data" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", path: "e:\mongodb\logs\mongo.log" } }
2014-06-05T16:00:31.860-0700 [initandlisten] journal dir=e:\mongodb\data\journal
2014-06-05T16:00:31.861-0700 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2014-06-05T16:00:31.902-0700 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2014-06-05T16:00:31.902-0700 [websvr] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:10048 Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. for socket: 0.0.0.0:28017
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to enable the web interface for mongod - it does not start by default. If you start mongodb this way:

```
mongod --rest
```

you should be able to connect to the web interface at 28017

Comment: It seems to me that REST is enabled and that is why it is trying to bind the port.  But it cannot because apparently the port is in use.

Comment: can you try restarting on a non-standard port, like 30001? e.g. mongod --port 30001 --rest . The purpose would be to see if you can then hit the web interface at 31001.

Comment: worked for me. have to do it everytime to be able to access `http://localhost:28017/`

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think this will help you out. 
Note i have not install msi. i have downloaded archive file and then run this command. but i believe running this command directly will help you

```
mongod --rest -dbpath ./data
```

Thanks